# Select rows from a DF in Python when these rows match all values in a list

Tags: arrays, dataframe, filter, match, contains

I have a list of values. If **all** values exist in the DataFrame I want to filter these records. If only one value exists, this is not a match so nothing should happen.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2,5]

DF = Label Value
     A       1
     B       2
     C       3
     D       4
```

With array A, I want to filter DF with value 1,2,3.
With array B nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

We define the following function that takes a dataframe `d` and a list `l`, and returns `d` filtered `d['Value`] in l`if all elements of`l`are present in`d['Value']`, and unfiletred` d` otherwise

```
def filter_if_all_exist(d, l):
    if not all([a in d['Value'] for a in l]):
        return d
    else:
        return d[[v in l for v in d['Value']]]
```

Now define our inputs

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2,5]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
Label Value
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
"""), delim_whitespace = True)
```

and apply our function. We have

```
filter_if_all_exist(df, A)
```

returns

```
    Label   Value
0   A       1
1   B       2
2   C       3
```

and

```
filter_if_all_exist(df, B)
```

returns

```
    Label   Value
0   A       1
1   B       2
2   C       3
3   D       4
```